# Closing BufferedWriter is erasing all file data written on file?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter, objectinputstream

I am getting continuous data from `ObjectInputStream` which I am writing on my file using `BufferedWriter` object.
I am checking file size which keeps on increasing. Now as soon as I stop discontinue the `while(true)` method with `false` which keeps on running this method I am closing my `BufferedWriter` object. After this operation whatever data were written on file are lost.

```
private void appendFile(JLabel jLab0x28, Socket client)
    {   
        try
        {   
            if(!continueMe)
            {   
                fileOut.close();
                fileOut = null;
                in.close();
                System.gc();
                jLab0x28.setText("<html> <font color='red'> Socket is closed  "+client.isClosed()+" </font> </html>");
                System.out.println("File size after discontinuing  "+
                        humanReadableByteCount(new File("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt").length(), true) );
            }

            if(!client.isClosed())
            {   
                try
                {   
                    String data = in.readObject().toString();
                    System.out.println("File size is  "+
                            humanReadableByteCount(new File("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt").length(), true) );
                    fileOut.append(data);
                    fileOut.flush();
                }
                catch (EOFException exp)
                {   
                    continueMe = true;
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("A Stream has finished "+exp.toString()+"\n");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) 
                {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(exp.toString());
                    continueMe = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            try 
            {
                fileOut.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception "+exp.toString());
            jLab0x28.setText(exp.getMessage());
            continueMe = false;
        }
    }
public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }
```

Logged Data:

```
File size is  118.3 kB
File size is  118.4 kB
File size is  118.5 kB
File size is  118.7 kB
File size is  118.8 kB
File size is  118.9 kB
File size is  119.1 kB
File size is  119.2 kB
File size is  119.3 kB
Done
Closed Socket connection from client
File size after discontinuing  0 B
```

Comment: if you don't post `humanReadableByteCount` code is hard to know...

Comment: Its just an code which returns file size. Check updated question now

Comment: The code looks quite suspicious as well. Passing a `Socket` as a parameter like that...that's not good.

Comment: I know, but this is not creating an issue. i have just used FileWriter instead and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the outputstream. Currently you are doing that in the `catch` clause which is not reached if you encounter no `IOException` (and you do not expect this)

```
catch(IOException exp)
        {
            try 
            {
                fileOut.close();
            } 
  ...
```

Modify your code like this

```
catch(IOException exp)
        {

            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception "+exp.toString());
            jLab0x28.setText(exp.getMessage());
            continueMe = false;
        }
try 
{
     fileOut.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) 
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Yes but it will be as good good as putting it just after i write a data like fileOut.write(data); fileOut.flush(); fileOut.close(); which will lead me to exception as soon as loop continues. I have just resolved it using FileWriter but i am still keen to understand it.

Comment: Put `fileOut.close()` after the loop, when you will no longer write or since you use append you can open and close in every loop iteration, but it is way less efficient

Comment: i did it, this gave me java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: In the code you posted there is no loop and would be impossible to point your exact mistake, but you are writing to the ouput stream after you called `close()` on it _java.io.IOException: Stream closed_

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here i have used FileWriter object intsead of BufferedWriter and now my file data is not getting erased. All code are same it's just change of Object that did the trick for me.

```
public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }

    private void appendFile(JLabel jLab0x28, Socket client)
    {   
        try
        {   
            if(!continueMe)
            {   
                //fileOut.close();
                //fileOut = null;
                fw.close();
                fw = null;
                in.close();
                System.gc();
                jLab0x28.setText("<html> <font color='red'> Socket is closed  "+client.isClosed()+" </font> </html>");
                System.out.println("File size after discontinuing  "+
                        humanReadableByteCount(new File("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt").length(), true) );
            }

            if(!client.isClosed())
            {   
                try
                {   
                    String data = in.readObject().toString();
                    System.out.println("File size is  "+
                            humanReadableByteCount(new File("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt").length(), true) );
                    fw.write(data);
                    fw.flush();
                    //fileOut.write(data);
                    //fileOut.flush();

                }
                catch (EOFException exp)
                {   
                    continueMe = true;
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("A Stream has finished "+exp.toString()+"\n");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) 
                {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(exp.toString());
                    continueMe = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            try 
            {
                //fileOut.close();
                fw.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception "+exp.toString());
            jLab0x28.setText(exp.getMessage());
            continueMe = false;
        }
    }


File size is  1.8 MB
File size is  1.8 MB
File size is  1.8 MB
Done
Closed Socket connection from client
File size after discontinuing  1.8 MB
```